# JMeter Recording is working fine, but the browser is not loading all controls on the browsers

Tags: jmeter

I am recording a website having lots of graphs and few dropdown lists.
When I am accessing the website via system proxy, the website is working fine. but as soon as I start recording via a proxy, few controls are not getting loaded properly.
i.e. the page is loading partially. The graph is not loading and the dropdown filters are also not loading.
Observation is that the graph and the controls are not loading when recording with jmeter. Please note that requests are getting recorded but i cannot do any action on browser as not controls have loaded.

I have tried changing the port.
I have checked and there is not firewall issues.
I have enabled all JS related settings for browser.
I have enabled the setting in HTTP requests default to retrieve all resources and parallelly.

**Below image when using Systems Proxy:**

[image]

**After using the Proxy and recording via JMeter**

[image]

Comment: You need to look at the request on network tab of browser which may have blocked because of the proxy, make sure you install Jmeter root.ca certificate in browser to handle *https* traffic.

Comment: I checked and didn't find any requests getting blocked. Also certificate is installed properly.

Comment: I am getting this error for the blocked requests. What is below WSS protocol ?::::::
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://abcd/8345344d-ac39-4f22-b377-0a2c96e81293?reloadUri=https://abcd-map-hdr.html.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), in case of any issues you should find the reason or at least a clue there.

The most frequent explanation would be failure of the [SSL handshake](https://www.ssl.com/article/ssl-tls-handshake-overview/), make sure to:

- import JMeter's self-signed certificate into your browser, see **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)  user manual entry for instructions
- clear your browsing data as some requests might be failing due to certificates mismatch, i.e. because of [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)

You can also try out an alternative recording solution like [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/)

With regards to the "chart" - it depends on the underlying technology, as it evidenced by its name JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder is only capable of intercepting HTTP or HTTPS requests, other protocols/technologies are not supported so if it is your case you will have to find another [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) or [Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)

Comment: I am getting this error in logs : Software aborted the connection : Socket write error.  Also I can see the blocked content is actually the images and fonts.